# Docker won;t start inside a docker container

Tags: docker

I am tyring to install docker inside a docker container, so i pulled a centos7 image and enabled systemd in it.

So i created a container from the image and then tried to install docker in it.

However for some reasons i am not able to start the docker service, Here is output of the commands from the container

**systemctl start docker**

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**systemctl status docker**

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-12-15 10:27:16 UTC; 23s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 574 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dockerd -H unix:// $DOCKER_OPTS (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 574 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Dec 15 10:27:16 c16893d50c15 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service RestartSec=2s expired, scheduling restart.
Dec 15 10:27:16 c16893d50c15 systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Dec 15 10:27:16 c16893d50c15 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 15 10:27:16 c16893d50c15 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 15 10:27:16 c16893d50c15 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 15 10:27:16 c16893d50c15 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

**dockerd --debug**

```
INFO[2020-12-15T10:28:08.589710537Z] Starting up
DEBU[2020-12-15T10:28:08.590585826Z] Listener created for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
DEBU[2020-12-15T10:28:08.591290544Z] Golang's threads limit set to 56070
INFO[2020-12-15T10:28:08.591784686Z] parsed scheme: "unix" module=grpc
INFO[2020-12-15T10:28:08.591807273Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme module=grpc
DEBU[2020-12-15T10:28:08.591814663Z] metrics API listening on /var/run/docker/metrics.sock
INFO[2020-12-15T10:28:08.591843833Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: [{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2020-12-15T10:28:08.591955801Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2020-12-15T10:28:08.593614061Z] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-12-15T10:28:08.593646287Z] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-12-15T10:28:08.593672812Z] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2020-12-15T10:28:08.593683296Z] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
DEBU[2020-12-15T10:28:08.594523308Z] Using default logging driver json-file
DEBU[2020-12-15T10:28:08.594622712Z] [graphdriver] priority list: [btrfs zfs overlay2 fuse-overlayfs aufs overlay devicemapper vfs]
DEBU[2020-12-15T10:28:08.594661302Z] processing event stream                       module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
DEBU[2020-12-15T10:28:08.604556675Z] backingFs=xfs, projectQuotaSupported=false, indexOff="index=off,"  storage-driver=overlay2
INFO[2020-12-15T10:28:08.604588162Z] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2
DEBU[2020-12-15T10:28:08.604606372Z] Initialized graph driver overlay2
DEBU[2020-12-15T10:28:08.610134017Z] No quota support for local volumes in /var/lib/docker/volumes: Filesystem does not support, or has not enabled quotas
DEBU[2020-12-15T10:28:09.564927998Z] Cleaning up old mountid : start.
failed to start daemon: error while opening volume store metadata database: timeout
```

**docker info**

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.0-docker)

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

Comment: Running Docker in Docker is technically a little tricky, and is usually discouraged.  What's your eventual goal?  Why not use the prebuilt `docker:dind` image?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes that's correct it is tricky i too got to understand since past two days, well the goal is to have centos7 with docker and use it for a various use cases... i have a vm with similar setup but now trying to replicate it as a container

Comment: Use the working VM.  It might be helpful to think of a container as a wrapper around a single process; if you want "CentOS" and "various use cases" and not some specific application, a VM is a better match.  (Systemd and Docker also don't play nicely, and I'd recommend avoiding systemd if at all possible.)

Comment: `--privilege` option might enable this, but I don't recommend. Only wanna let container run on container, [containerd](https://containerd.io/) might be good choice.

Comment: @AkihitoKIRISAKI --privilege i used to create and run container with --privilege option, but still it did not work for me.